# Gitchangelog plugin error "bjurr.gitchangelog.api.exceptions.GitChangelogIntegrationException"

Tags: java, gitlab, mediawiki, changelog

Error while posting content from jenkin Git changelog plugin to mediawiki

```
bjurr.gitchangelog.api.exceptions.GitChangelogIntegrationException
```

Full error:

> atse.bjurr.gitchangelog.internal.integrations.mediawiki.MediaWikiClient.createMediaWikiPage(MediaWikiClient.java:95)
>   at
>   se.bjurr.gitchangelog.api.GitChangelogApi.toMediaWiki(GitChangelogApi.java:134)
>   at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitchangelog.perform.RemoteCallable.call(RemoteCallable.java:167)
>   at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitchangelog.perform.RemoteCallable.call(RemoteCallable.java:29)
>   at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1085) at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitchangelog.perform.GitChangelogPerformer.performerPerform(GitChangelogPerformer.java:40)
>   at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitchangelog.GitChangelogRecorder.perform(GitChangelogRecorder.java:52)
>   at
>   hudson.tasks.BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.perform(BuildStepCompatibilityLayer.java:81)
>   at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
>   at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:730)
>   at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:676)
>   at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186) at
>   hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:621)
>   at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1760) at
>   hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43) at
>   hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97) at
>   hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:415) Caused by:
>   com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: Missing property in path
>   $['login'] at
>   com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.PathToken.handleObjectProperty(PathToken.java:72)
>   at
>   com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.PropertyPathToken.evaluate(PropertyPathToken.java:77)
>   at
>   com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.RootPathToken.evaluate(RootPathToken.java:62)
>   at
>   com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.CompiledPath.evaluate(CompiledPath.java:53)
>   at
>   com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.CompiledPath.evaluate(CompiledPath.java:61)
>   at com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:187) at
>   com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.JsonContext.read(JsonContext.java:164) at
>   com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.JsonContext.read(JsonContext.java:151) at
>   com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:502) at
>   se.bjurr.gitchangelog.internal.integrations.mediawiki.MediaWikiClient.getWikiToken(MediaWikiClient.java:192)
>   at
>   se.bjurr.gitchangelog.internal.integrations.mediawiki.MediaWikiClient.doAuthenticate(MediaWikiClient.java:177)
>   at
>   se.bjurr.gitchangelog.internal.integrations.mediawiki.MediaWikiClient.createMediaWikiPage(MediaWikiClient.java:86)

Comment: Does this provide you some sort of a hint `com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: Missing property in path $['login'] at ` ? Since your query has not much of an information, its hard to guess for me as to what could be wrong.

Comment: Yes it do provide the com.jayway.jsonpath.PathNotFoundException: Missing property in path $['login'] error.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue here: https://github.com/tomasbjerre/git-changelog-lib/issues/51
And also asked here: [Cannot authenticate with MediaWiki 1.28 API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45779754/cannot-authenticate-with-mediawiki-1-28-api)

I'm not sure if this functionality works or not. As far as I know I do follow the API correctly but I have not been able to actually create a page during the last year.