# Cannot authenticate with MediaWiki 1.28 API

Tags: mediawiki-api

I'm having problems authenticating with MediaWiki API in MediaWiki 1.28.

The API: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page

My exact attempt: https://github.com/tomasbjerre/git-changelog-lib/tree/feature/medawiki

How I'm doing it:

```
Authenticating to http://localhost:8889/w
Posting to: http://localhost:8889/w/api.php?action=query&meta=tokens&format=json&type=login
Got cookie: mediawiki_session=pnbmq5t2cq8gsnv4cm74lb6f3aa5vbeb; path=/; HttpOnly
Response: {"batchcomplete":"","query":{"tokens":{"logintoken":"bc18a93aedd4993634ddb8e28e6cd60259993ca3+\\"}}}
Using logintoken: bc18a93aedd4993634ddb8e28e6cd60259993ca3+\
Posting to: http://localhost:8889/w/api.php?action=login&format=json
Using cookie: mediawiki_session=pnbmq5t2cq8gsnv4cm74lb6f3aa5vbeb; path=/; HttpOnly
Post content: lgname=User%40botuser&lgpassword=*&lgtoken=bc18a93aedd4993634ddb8e28e6cd60259993ca3%2B%5C
Response: {"login":{"result":"Failed","reason":"The supplied credentials could not be authenticated."}}
```

I am using this compose to fiddle with MediaWiki 1.28:
https://github.com/pastakhov/compose-mediawiki-ubuntu

I have created a bot-user that I am using to authenticate.

When using maintenance script eval.php like this:

```
root@9b3370557c92:/# cd /var/www/html/w/maintenance 
root@9b3370557c92:/var/www/html/w/maintenance# php eval.php
```

And having a bot like this:

[image]

I get responses like:

```
> echo BotPassword::login( "User@newbot", "odqp6am3aerd6pa4gikm17d87a4r26dh", RequestContext::getMain()->getRequest() )->getMessage()->getKey();
internalerror_info
```

And if I dont prefix with User@ (ignoring what Mediawiki bot creation page suggests)

```
> echo BotPassword::login( "newbot", "odqp6am3aerd6pa4gikm17d87a4r26dh", RequestContext::getMain()->getRequest() )->getMessage()->getKey();     
botpasswords-invalid-name
```

[The documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Login) here is a mess. I would suggest rewriting it exclusively for 1.28 and keep the current page for legacy users.

Answer (score 0):

`lgname` should be `botuser`. (And if you aren't yet, you should be using a [bot password](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Bot_passwords).)

Comment: Changing lgname to botuser does not work.

Where do you see botuser mentioned? I see lgname here: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Login

Comment: In your log snippet, where you are prefixing it with `User:` which you should not be doing.

Comment: No that does not work.

I prefix with User@ because that is what the wiki page says when I create the bot user.

Here is the outbut if not prefixing:

botuser=mybotuser&lgpassword=*&lgtoken=6b30995007a8267081b65cd51c308261599d0563%2B%5C
Response: {"login":{"result":"Failed","reason":"The supplied credentials could not be authenticated."}}

Comment: Incorrect log in my previous comment. Here it is:
Response: {"batchcomplete":"","query":{"tokens":{"logintoken":"62033f38dae0cba4f2689e3a2185e3fd599dac90+\\"}}}
Using logintoken: 62033f38dae0cba4f2689e3a2185e3fd599dac90+\
Posting to: http://localhost:8889/w/api.php?action=login&format=json
Using cookie: mediawiki_session=fbhqn6r71vld4i8vmd3otvqimq3bv1i3; path=/; HttpOnly
Post content: lgname=mybotuser&lgpassword=*&lgtoken=62033f38dae0cba4f2689e3a2185e3fd599dac90%2B%5C
Response: {"login":{"result":"Failed","reason":"The supplied credentials could not be authenticated."}}

Comment: Oh, sorry, I jumped to the wrong conclusion. If you are already using a bot password, you are doing something wrong, though - that message does not come from the bot password checking logic, it comes from the normal authentication logic which shouldn't even be invoked for a bot password.

Comment: Can you check what's written to the `authentication` log channel? (See [log channel docs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:How_to_debug#Creating_custom_log_groups))

Comment: I'm updating the original question with authentication log.

Comment: So in the first snippet, MediaWiki did *not* recognize this as a bot password login (otherwise there would have been a password error notice), then none of the configured login providers recognized the user + password pair, which means you either disabled normal password authentication somehow  (`LocalPasswordPrimaryAuthenticationProvider` was removed from [`$wgAuthManagerAutoConfig`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgAuthManagerAutoConfig)) or the user does not exist.

Comment: (Are you sure the bot password for the given name exists? Chances are, you are submitting something like `<username>@<botname>` with a non-existent botname, so the bot password check ignores it for that reason, and the normal login ignores it because it tries to use the full thing as a username.) The second snippet is confusing as there are three different failure reasons there, each of which

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I'm trying without <username>@... and with it. With several bot-users... I would suggest rewriting https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page for 1.28. Copy the current page to a legacy page and have the API-page exclusivly describing 1.28 complete with curl commands.

Comment: I don't think there is anything on that page that wouldn't be valid for 1.28. Here is a code snippet you can try to diagnose the problem (run it with `maintenance/eval.php`): `echo BotPassword::login( <username>, <password>, RequestContext::getMain()->getRequest() )->getMessage()->getKey();`

Comment: `interenalerror_info` means the login was successful (it gives an error since `getMessage` calls are not allowed on success), so there is indeed nothing wrong with that username and password. Getting the `supplied credentials...` error should be impossible in that case. Sorry, I don't have other suggestions, sort of stepping through the authentication process in a debugger.

Comment: Or if you just want to get things to work, you could  install the [OAuth](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:OAuth) extension and use an [owner-only consumer](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/OAuth/Owner-only_consumers), that uses a completely different code path for authentication.